# Save multiple values in NSUserDefaults key

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Is there any way to save multiple values for the same key in `NSUserDefaults`? I seem to only be saving the last value, even though I have multiple values for the "Day" key.

`Day`:

```
for days in results! {
    let nD = DayClass()
    nD.dayOfTheWeek = days[“D”] as! String
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(nD.dayOfTheWeek, forKey: “Day”)
}
```

I've tried creating an array as a possible solution, but I'm still only getting the last value when I log it in my console:

```
var emptyArray = [String]()
emptyArray.append(dayOfTheWeek)
print("Array: \(emptyArray)")
print("ArrayCount: \(emptyArray.count)")
```

Comment: You are storing the value on the same key.
You should use different keys or an array.

Try changing the word "Day" to another word in each day

Comment: I'm using an API to pull in the values, so I don't think I can change the word "Day" to another word in each day since the days of the week all come as a result under the same key from the API ya know?

Comment: Then I would use an array and save this array with the key "Day". You can edit this array every time you load it from the user defaults and then store it again.

Comment: @marc14 `let dayArray = defaults.objectForKey("Day")`? or something different?

Comment: To save: 

`defaults.setObject(array, forKey: "Day")`

To read:
`if let testArray : AnyObject? = defaults.objectForKey("Day") {
    var readArray : [String] = testArray! as [String]
}`

Comment: I'm not sure I see how that is different from what I've tried in my code in my question.  I might be missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. First check if there is already an Day array in the prefs. If so then add the new dayOfTheWeek to that array and store it. Else create a new one and store it.

```
for days in results! {
    let dayOfTheWeek = days["D"] as! String
    //check if there is already an existing Day array in prefs
    if var existingArr = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("Day") as? [String] {
        //if so append the new value to that array and store it
        if existingArr.contains(dayOfTheWeek) == false {
            existingArr.append(dayOfTheWeek)
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setObject(existingArr, forKey: "Day")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
    } else {
        //create a new array and store it
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject([dayOfTheWeek], forKey: "Day")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it keeps saving the same stuff over and over.  So each time I stop and run the app again, it re-saves the days I've already saved.  So I have Monday saved multiple times in the array, etc. Is there any way for it to not do that?

Comment: You can easily fix that by checking if the day is present in the array before appending it. I've updated the answer so that the value is saved to the array only if its not already present.

Comment: Yeah it was giving me an error on the first line of `xcode cannot convert value of type string to expected argument type @noescape (anyobject) throws -> bool`

Comment: You can change to `if (existingArry as! [String]).contains(dayOfTheWeek)`.

Comment: That helped the error to go away but didn't stop the problem with it saving the same stuff over and over

Comment: I have updated the code. There was a problem with the code. Now it will append the value if its not already there. Check this and see if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
let daysArray = ["Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tu", "Wed", "Th", "Fri"]
// Set Array Into NSUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults().setObject(daysArray, forKey: "day")

// Retrive Array from NSUserDefaults
if let daysOfWeek = NSUserDefaults().arrayForKey("day") as? [String] {
  for item in daysOfWeek {
    print(item)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the days of the week from an API, so I can't hardcode them in there on `daysArray`.  Does that make sense? How would I set up `daysArray` in that case?

Comment: After getting the data array from your API then save the array into NSUserDefaults. You don't need to do exact what I have done. I have just shown you how to save data and retain again from NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to save them into an array like my code shows in my question at the end, but it keeps over writing the values so I only have one value in the array, you know?

Answer (score 0):

```
   var food: [String] 
                            {


   get {

        if let returnValue = 
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("food") as? [String] {
            return returnValue
        } else {
            return ["muesli", "banana"] //Default value
        }
    }
    set {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue, forKey: "food")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(food) // prints: ["muesli", "banana"] (at first launch)

    food = ["cake"]
    print(food) // prints: ["cake"]

    food += ["spaghetti"]
    print(food) // prints: ["cake", "spaghetti"]

    food = []
    print(food) // prints: []

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nil, forKey: "food")
    print(food) // prints: ["muesli", "banana"]
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding lazy var food, then it only executes when you call it. Also you don't have to call synchronize explicitly.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are doing here as related to my code, can you explain a bit more if you get a chance?  Thanks!